# Keras: IndexError: tuple index out of range - Conv2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new in Keras and Tensorflow. I am trying to run some specific code based on Keras and Tensorflow. In that code, I prepared dataset from tfrecordes files and reshape it with `tf.reshape(image, [32, 32, 3])`, in my model, I need to apply a Conv2D layer on this image output, I using Keras, in my code below:

```
# Image
x = k.layers.Input(shape=input_shape,tensor=img)
# ReLU Conv1
conv1 = k.layers.Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = 9, strides=1,padding='valid', activation='relu', name='conv1')(x)
```

the problem is that, when I run the code, I got this error:

> self.kernel_size[i],
>   IndexError: tuple index out of range

so, after many searches, I found that this error may be fixed by change Keras version from 2.2 to 1.2.
I do that but actually, I must change all of my code, do anybody how can fix this error just in Keras 2.2, without using Keras 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a 9 * 9 kernel. Change `kernel_size=9` to `kernel_size=( 9 , 9 )`
Edited code line :

```
conv1 = k.layers.Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = ( 9 , 9 ), strides=1,padding='valid', activation='relu', name='conv1')(x)
```

Comment: this change has not any effect!